# How can I customize bashrc, bash_profile or profile on a CoreOS installation?

Tags: coreos

I fully realize that CoreOS is meant to be mostly immutable so that nothing is installed in the userspace. And for 99% of the use-cases I agree. I'm using CoreOS/toolbox when I need to get some actual work done but I also need to slightly update the user environment so that I can properly Docker-ify my development environment.

Comment: The repository you linked is not public...

Comment: I modify my coreos installation with the cloud-config file.  Are you using a cloud-config? If so, you can get a lot of mileage with write_files: in the config, as well as installing your own stuff in the units: section.  I install kubernetes on top of coreos, so the base coreos is augmented significantly.

Answer (score 14):

The .bashrc is a symlink to a read-only file. All you need to do is:

```
cd $HOME
rm .bashrc
cp /usr/share/skel/.bashrc .
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution is also encouraged by a member of the CoreOS team: "Replacing the symlink with a copy of the file is the correct approach. CoreOS won't touch that file on updates and it will let you make arbitrary modifications." - https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/1342#issuecomment-241726123

Answer (score 0):

I must have missed something. CoreOS users do not include a `.bashrc` file and so that's where I was able to connect my `.profile`. I'm surprised that CoreOS did not do the right thing by executing the .profile but as I've never been 100% certain how bash starts (and I should). In the meantime I simply created my own `.bashrc` file:

```
# .bashrc
[[ -f ~/.profile ]] && . ~/.profile
```

and it worked sufficiently. Of course any incompatibility between my `.profile` and changes in the CoreOS alpha channel could render the account inoperable.

[here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html) is some good docs that I also misread; quoted here:

> 3.1.2.3. ~/.profile
>
> In the absence of ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile is
>   read. It can hold the same configurations, which are then also
>   accessible by other shells. Mind that other shells might not
>   understand the Bash syntax.